# Installation of windows 8.1 in Dell Precision T3400

Tags: windows-8.1, dell-precision

I got myself a T3400 PC. I installed windows 8.1 in it. Everything seems to work fine except for my internal speakers.

After I installed windows 8.1 the audio symbol showed that it was muted at the bottom right corner and no matter what I did the volume level wouldn't change.

I went to Dell's website and downloaded their latest audio driver by entering my express code into the website.

The muted symbol has gone away but I'm still not hearing anything from my speakers even though I see the signal level changing in "Playback Device" tab of my sound devices.

I plugged in my headphones and mic they're working fine.

I ran Dell's hardware test on the PC and it passed everything.

Q1. Is there any way to get them working ?

Q2. Do I need to install some new driver?

Comment: It sounds like the speakers no longer work because of a hardware reason not software.